# How to convert find-should into new expect syntax?

Tags: rspec, cucumber, capybara

How would I go about modifying the below code to use the new expect syntax instead of the deprecated should syntax?

```
find("#iframe").should be_visible
```

I tried using

```
expect("#iframe").to be_visible
```

But I kept getting an expectation not met when running it. Since this is an iframe, I think I need to use find first before the iframe can be detected, but I'm not sure how to implement find with expect.

Answer (score 0):

A direct translation would be:

```
expect(find('#iframe')).to be_visible
```

However, it would be better to do:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('#iframe')
```

Both approaches will give the same pass/fail result. However, the error message for the approach that uses `find` is misleading. The `find` method will raise an ElementNotFound exception, rather than allowing the test assertion to fail.